# proving lim of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

My question is the following:

$x_n$  is a series.

also $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} (x_{n+1}-x_n)=c$
is given.

I need to prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{c_n}{n}\right)=c$$
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you meant either $\;\sum x_n\;$ is a series of else $\;\{x_n\}\;$ is a *sequence*...?

Answer (score 5):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $m$ such that $|x_n-x_{n-1}-c|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>m$. We have $$\left|\frac{x_n}n-c\right|=\left|\frac{x_1+(x_2-x_1)+\cdots+(x_n-x_{n-1})}n-c\right|=\left|\frac{[x_1-c]+[(x_2-x_1)-c]+\cdots+[(x_n-x_{n-1})-c]}n\right|\\\leq\frac{|x_1-c|}n+\sum_{ k=2}^n\frac{|x_k-x_{k-1}-c|}n\\=\frac{|x_1-c|}n+\sum_{ k=2}^m\frac{|x_k-x_{k-1}-c|}n+\sum_{ k=m+1}^n\frac{|x_k-x_{k-1}-c|}n\\ \leq\frac{|x_1-c|}n+\sum_{ k=2}^m\frac{|x_k-x_{k-1}-c|}n+\frac{\varepsilon\,(n-m+1)}n
$$
As $n\to\infty$, this last expression goes to $\varepsilon$. So we have shown that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x_n}n-c\right|\leq\varepsilon.
$$
But $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x_n}n-c\right|=0.
$$

Comment: Could you explain why the second line is correct?

Comment: Because $c=\frac{cn}n$.